# Ugly fonts Netbeans on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: netbeans

I'm newer here, but a have a problem a far time. So, the fonts of the Netbeans is very very ugly. Others applications same Android Studio e Eclipse has better fonts.

I'm using Java Oracle 8.

It's this problem guys.

Thanks.

[image: See this:]

Comment: Have you tried another font?

Comment: Yes, but the same result.

Comment: Solution  >> http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=173772#173772

Comment: Please post your solution here too (and *accept* it). This topic might help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem uninstalling Java Oracle and installing OpenJDK 8.
For applying changes, I reinstalled all software/IDE who use Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the default look and feel of netbeans instead of using GTK.

You can check if it works lunching Netbeans like this :

```
netbeans --laf Nimbus
```

If it works we need to set it as default.

Let's edit the configuration file of netbeans, in my case **~/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf**.

We find the options part and we add the --laf Nimbus option. In my case the final version is like this one :

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true --laf Nimbus"
```

Now is much more confortable than before.

Answer (score 1):

I've found usefull on my laptop to set in netbeans.conf:

```
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

"lcd" settings are the best choice for me, if we are talking about fonts in Netbeans on Linux.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 it is: `-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` to netbeans.conf that do the trick for me